# bash script flock() locking and starting service

Tags: linux, bash, shell, flock

I want to use `flock` to make sure only once instance of script is running at any given time.

Script skeleton looks like this:

```
ME=`basename "$0"`;
LOCK="/tmp/${ME}.LCK";
exec 8>$LOCK;



if flock -n -x 8; then
    do things

     if [ condition ]; then
       /path/asterisk_restart.sh
     fi
else
    echo "$(date) script already running >> $log_file"

fi
```

Now the script `/path/asterisk_restart.sh` do many things, but in the end asterisk is stopped and last command is `service asterisk start`

The problem is this: as file handles and locks are shared across `fork()/exec()`, 8 filehandle remained locked in asterisk process, so the script will not run again once `/path/asterisk_restart.sh` is executed (and asterisk are not stopped/restarted by other means outside this script)

So my approach is to start sub-shell and close 8 file handle just before executing `/path/asterisk_restart.sh`.

It looks like this:

```
    ME=`basename "$0"`;
    LOCK="/tmp/${ME}.LCK";
    exec 8>$LOCK;



    if flock -n -x 8; then
         do things

         if [ condition ]; then
            (
               exec 8>&-
               /path/asterisk_restart.sh
            )
         fi
    else
        echo "$(date) script already running >> $log_file"

    fi
```

Is this a sound approach?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent scripts against parallel run, I would suggest something like this.

```
if mkdir $LockDir; then
    echo "Locking succeeded" >&2
    # Your script here. 
    rm -f $LockDir
else
    echo "Lock failed - exit" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Using a directory instead of a file is better because mkdir is an atomic operation and hence would eliminate the race condition.

Also don't put your LockDir inside /tmp. If it gets removed, the lock is gone.

The only problem with the above implementation is that it does not work when the LockDir gets removed by some other script.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this does not answer my question. First of all, I am using flock, not simple check if file exists. Flock is atomic too,  It also works if server is restarted unexpectedly, and temporary files/directories remain.